# Why does MongoDB have a 100MB limit per aggregation pipeline stage?

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework, nosql

Why does MongoDB have a [100MB limit per aggregation pipeline stage](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#memory-restrictions)?

You can set `allowDiskUse` to extend this limit.

My question is, why the number 100MB?

Comment: there had to be an arbitrary limit before spilling to use the disk. I think no matter what number was picked, the question would arise "why that particular number".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you won't get the exact answer unless you get it from the mongodb core developers.

The idea was to have a threshold limit before using the disk. 100MB is the max in-memory threshold mongodb has put not only for aggregation pipeline operations but also compact operation as well.

> 100MB is just a arbitrary number and as for my knowledge the 100MB
>   limit was because if we consider each document to be of size 100KB and
>   each pipeline returns 1000 documents so it reaches 100MB limit.

Answer (score 3):

I really think that this 100mb in memory limit on aggregation pipeline stages should be configurable. It's not 2014 anymore, hardware changes and the scenario that Mongo is running in from company to company and application to application is always different. Picking an arbitrary 100mb limit and then not allowing it to be modified isn't helping anyone. 100mb should be the default, not the only option.

See my "idea" for making this limit configurable on the MongoDB site, and upvote it if you agree.

https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/924280-database/suggestions/40081492-allow-configuration-of-100mb-memory-limit-per-aggr

Answer (score 0):

Both @Sam Leach and @mohamedrias according to http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/limits/

> Pipeline stages have a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. If a stage exceeds this limit, MongoDB will produce an error

Therefore if the 100MB limit is exceeded the disk will not be used but the execution will fail!

I think that the aforementioned memory limit is set because if MongoDB undoubtedly allocated memory this would cause problems to the other co-hosted programs. This way MongoDB is sandboxed.

Comment: This answer is wrong; if you set `allowDiskUse` parameter to `true`, disk will be used and there won't be any error even if pipeline stage exceeds 100MB of RAM... [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#memory-restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

This limitation is described in MongoDB Core Server bug ticket [SERVER-40317](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-40317)
titled "**$facet** execution has no limit on how much memory it can consume"